# Google colab runtime crashes everytime I start training the model, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

The code of snippet causes the runtime to crashes, I am using GPU runtime with a training subset of 10000 images

```
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x_subset), np.array(train_y_subset), batch_size=10000, epochs=15, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Please try again by decreasing the `batch_size` in `model.fit()`. Could you also share minimal reproducible code along with the error log to better understand the issue.